# How to abort saving in a before-save-hook function?

Tags: hooks, error-handling

If, in a function run from `before-save-hook`, I want to *abort* the saving of a file, so that the file is not saved and the user is signaled, how can I do that?  Is it possible (without rebinding <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> or doing `defadvice` around `save-buffer`)?

(It used to be, I think in Emacs 23, that all you had to do was `(error "Bad!")`, and the file save operation would be aborted.  But that does no longer work; any errors in a `before-save-hook` are ignored.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using one of the hooks `write-file-functions` or `write-contents-functions` instead.  Your hook function can signal an error or just return non-nil, and in either case it will abort the save.

Comment: If the hook function simply returns non-`nil`, the buffer will be marked as saved (i.e. not modified), and cause subsequent save-buffer operations to be ignored, since the file is considered “saved”.  But signaling an error works!

Comment: Huh.  For me, returning non-nil aborts the save and doesn't mark the buffer as modified (which surprised me, since I was expecting the behavior you describe).